# Space and non-Latin characters in URL

Tags: php, url, encoding, pretty-urls

I want my URLs to be as much human-readable and pretty as possible. I noticed even space character works in URL. Copy:`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince of Persia` or `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/سنڌي` to your borowers' address bar, and it works!

These work too:

```
<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince of Persia'> Foo </a>
<a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/سنڌي'> Bar </a>
```

How much safe is using Unicode letter beyond A-Z in URLs? My URLs are simple without any punctuation mark, similar to Wikipedia links.

It's not important for me that it is valid or invalid, I only want it works!

(actually I am going to use `+` instead of '' and my main concern is about Unicode text)

Does above works hassle-free in all common browsers?

Comment: It won't work consistently because it's not valid :) Browsers don't have to encode it for you AFAIK. It's like with invalid HTML... sure it works but it works differently in every browser and you always just wish you got strict instant error instead...

Comment: What differences do you mean?

Comment: well see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15547897/995876 for instance

Answer (score 0):

This is completely browser dependent as it's just a UI gimmick. The actual URL used is the encoded one and if you try to copy-paste it, you'll see that your clipboard has the URL in URL encoding.

Comment: @PHPst what do you mean by use? It is safe to write those characters literally in the supporting browsers when using them, but in your code you must url-encode.

Answer (score 0):

When you call "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince of Persia" its your browser doing magic behind the scene. Space char is converted to %20 escape format and sent to web server. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince%20of%20Persia

Wikipedia however does not return you the real page just yet. Your browser receives redirect reply with the underscore format. Then your browser downloads the real content. Its wikipedia server business logic to sanitize visible urls.
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia

You just put your browser and internet working harder :-)

Any unicode letter is fine, they are %XX escaped before sent to web browser. Here is a real url format seen by destination web server.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B3%D9%86%DA%8C%D9%8A

Its up to web server know how to handle UTF8 unicode escaping, most modern servers know what to do. Smart browsers can convert %XX escapes to visible letters in an address bar field. When you doing http calls programmatically you need to know how escaping works.